# Label not being added to Google Map marker

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my code I load the map then after a search is done populating a table the map then uses that data to plot out markers. I cannot get the markers to have labels regardless of what I try.

```
 var map = null;
 var geocoder = null;
 var point = null;

function DoIt() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(28.55074, -82.42082), 10);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

        // Function for handling zooms 
        GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", function (oldzoomlevel, zoomlevel) {
            document.getElementById('tbZoomLevel').value = zoomlevel;
        });

        GEvent.addListener(map, "dragend", function (overlay, point) {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            document.getElementById("tbX").value = center.lat();
            document.getElementById("tbY").value = center.lng();
        });
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

        <%= mapVolunteers() %>
    }
```

then I pull data from the data table returning the ID, x y coordinates and marker info as shown below.

```
   function createMarker(id, point, info) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point,{ title: "Id: " + id, label: "test" });
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(info);
            });
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function () {
                try {
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.fontSize = '8pt';
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.textDecoration = 'underline';
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.fontWeight = 'Bold';
                }
                catch (e)
                { }
            });
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function () {
                try {
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.fontSize = '8pt';
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.textDecoration = '';
                    document.getElementById(marker.idNumber).style.fontWeight = '';
                }
                catch (e)
                { }
            });
            return marker;
        }
```

Regardless of what I try labels of some sort never work. Currently my map works in the way that I want besides the labels. Hopefully this is an easy fix that does not require re-writing my existing code too much. What can I do to get a label with each icon or what am I missing? Preferably I would like the change to be on the api side rather than a 3rd party js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I can see is that you're instantiating your marker a little differently than usual. If you're using the Maps Javascript API, it's common to do this:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'title',
  label: 'A'
});
```

Here's the marker's documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker

Hope that helps.

Comment: The solution for me was to go maps api v3 and re-write a good chunk of my program because it was half v2 and half v3. Once I got that darn key to work...